# MYSQL giving different output on Windows 7 And Linux for same query

Tags: java, mysql, linux, windows-7

I have installed MySQL on Windows 7 and Red Hat Linux.

Windows 7 MySQL version  5.6.15 and
Red Hat Linux  MySQL version is 5.1.12

I have table `wf_params` with below schema

```
Field           Type          Collation        Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
--------------  ------------  ---------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
Id              bigint(20)    (NULL)           NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
Name            varchar(100)  utf8_unicode_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
LookupId        bigint(20)    (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
ExternalAuthId  bigint(20)    (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
LastSync        varchar(50)   utf8_unicode_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
TaskType        varchar(50)   utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references
```

it contains data :

```
    Id  TaskTypeId  TaskType  Name         Type    Operator  Value            Format  IsDefault  
------  ----------  --------  -----------  ------  --------  ---------------  ------  -----------
     1           2  Trigger   labels       String  EqualsTo  UNREAD,STARRED   (NULL)            1
     2           1  Trigger   albumName    String  EqualsTo  Timeline Photos  (NULL)            1
     3           2  Action    Email        String  EqualsTo  (NULL)           (NULL)            0
     4           7  Trigger   MachineList  String  (NULL)    (NULL)           (NULL)            0
```

When I execute Following query

```
SELECT UPPER( CONCAT(TaskType,'_',TaskTypeId)) 'OperationId'  , NAME , VALUE   
    FROM wf_params WHERE IsDefault = TRUE;
```

on Linux it gives me output like :

```
OperationId  NAME       VALUE            
-----------  ---------  -----------------
Trigger_2    labels     UNREAD,STARRED   
Trigger_1    albumName  Timeline Photos
```

but when I execute query on Windows 7 where MySQL is installed it gives me output

```
OperationId  NAME       VALUE            
-----------  ---------  -----------------
TRIGGER_2    labels     UNREAD,STARRED   
TRIGGER_1    albumName  Timeline Photos
```

Why this is happning? 
Why it's not converting to upper case on linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

Check the table case sensitivity. In particular note that on windows the table names are case-insensitive and on Linux they are case-sensitive.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html